# EditText and TextView etc

Tags: android, android-layout

In my code I use simple editText and textView, using editText get value, and calculation in main.java.
And write the result at textview.

But the problem is running in app, there is

> Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
>
> ...
>
> ...
>
> At com.example.jk.kktae0034_sec.MainActivity.
>   (MainActivity.java:52)

In line 52 is that

```
TextView recText = (TextView) findViewById (R.id.rec_WH); //here is first error

...

EditText editFck = (EditText) findViewById (R.id.fck); //if first error is // than here is occur error
```

---

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    Button btnCal;

    TextView recText = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.rec_WH);
    TextView wheelStr = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.wheelStr);
    TextView ironStr = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.ironStr);

    EditText editFck = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.fck);
    EditText editFy = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.fy);
    EditText edit_life_load = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.life_load);
    EditText edit_dead_load = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.dead_load);
    EditText editL = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.l);
    EditText editRatio = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.ratio);

    double b, d, roh, Mn, Mu, pi=0.85, w, L, fy, fck, roh_max, roh_min, h, a, c, beta1, strain_t, As;
    double life_load, dead_load, ratio;

    double AA[][] = {
        {9.53,71.3,142.6,213.9,285.2,356.5,427.8,499.1,570.4,641.7,713},
        {12.7,126.7,253.4,380,1,506.8,633.5,760.2,886.9,1014,1140},
        {15.9,198.6,397.2,595.8,794.4,993.0,1191,1390,1589,1787,1986},
        {19.1,286.5,573.0,859.5,1146,1433,1719,2006,2292,2579,2865},
        {22.2,387.1,774.2,1161,1548,1935,2322,2710,3097,3484,3871},
        {25.4,506.7,1013.4,1520,2027,2534,3040,3547,4054,4560,5067},
        {28.6,642.4,1285,1927,2570,3212,3854,4497,5139,5782,6424},
        {31.8,794.2,1588,2383,3177,3971,4765,5559,6354,7148,7942},
        {34.9,956.6,1913,2870,3826,4783,5740,6696,7653,8609,9566},
        {38.1,1140,2280,3420,4560,5700,6840,7980,9120,10260,11400}
    };

    int num[] = {10,13,16,19,22,25,29,32,35,38 };

    public void settingHeight(int i){
        int j, cnt=0;
        h = d + 0.5 * AA[i][0] + 12.7 + 40;
        for(j = 0; j < 10000; j++){
            if(j*10 > h){
                h = j*10;
                cnt++;
                break;
            }
            if(cnt > 0)
                break;
        }
        d = h - (0.5 * AA[i][0] + 12.7 + 40);
    }

    void reSetting(){
        a = As * fy / (0.85 * fck * b);
        c = a / beta1;
        strain_t = (d - c) / c * 0.003;
        if (strain_t > 0.005)
            pi = 0.85;
        else if (strain_t > 0.002)
            pi = 0.65 + (0.0043 - 0.002) * 200 / 3;
        else
            pi = 0.65;
        Mn = As * fy * (d - a / 2);
        Mu = pi * Mn;

        recText.setText("B = "+String.format("%.2f", b)+"mm, D = "+String.format("%.2f", d)+"mm");
        wheelStr.setText("Mu = "+String.format("%.2f", Mu/1000000)+"KN*m");
    }

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        fck = Double.parseDouble(editFck.getText().toString());
        fy = Double.parseDouble(editFy.getText().toString());
        life_load = Double.parseDouble(edit_life_load.getText().toString());
        dead_load = Double.parseDouble(edit_dead_load.getText().toString());
        L = Double.parseDouble(editL.getText().toString());
        ratio = Double.parseDouble(editRatio.getText().toString());

        btnCal = (Button)findViewById(R.id.btnCal);

        btnCal.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                //steel ratio
                roh = 0.85 * 0.85 * fck / fy * 0.003 / (0.003 + 0.005);

                //main
                w = 1.2 * dead_load + 1.6 * life_load;
                Mu = w * L*L / 8;

                //setting side
                int i, cnt = 0;
                double bdd;
                bdd = Mu*1000000 / (pi*roh*fy*(1 - 0.59*roh*fy / fck));
                bdd = bdd / (ratio*ratio);
                b = Math.pow(bdd,0.33333333);

                for (i = 1;i<=10000;i++) {
                    if (i * 10 > b)  {
                        b = i * 10;
                        cnt++;
                        break;
                    } if (cnt > 0)
                        break;
                }
                d = b * ratio;

                //setting steel
                int x, y, cnt_1, cnt_2;
                double Ass;
                Ass = roh * b * d;
                for (x = 0; x < 10; x++) {
                    for (y = 0; y < 10; y++) {
                        if (AA[x][y] >= Ass) {
                            roh_max = 0.85 * 0.85 * fck / fy * 0.003 / 0.007;
                            if (0.25 * Math.sqrt(fck) / fy > 1.4 / fy)
                                roh_min = 1.4 / fy;
                            else
                                roh_min = 0.25 * Math.sqrt(fck) / fy;
                            roh = AA[x][y] / b / d;
                            if (roh > roh_min && roh < roh_max) {
                                cnt_2 = y;
                                cnt_1 = x;
                                As = AA[x][y];

                                ironStr.setText("철근"+cnt_2+" -D "+num[cnt_1]);
                                settingHeight(cnt);
                                reSetting();
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Layout

```
<RelativeLayout
    android:id="@+id/mainRelayout">

    <RelativeLayout
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/input_text_Layout">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/life_load_text"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Life_Load"
            android:textSize="15pt"/>

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/dead_load_text"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Dead_Load"
            android:textSize="15pt"
            android:layout_below="@+id/life_load_text"/>

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/l_text"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="L"
            android:textSize="15pt"
            android:layout_below="@+id/dead_load_text"/>

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/fck_text"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Fck"
            android:textSize="15pt"
            android:layout_below="@+id/l_text"/>

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/fy_text"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Fy"
            android:textSize="15pt"
            android:layout_below="@+id/fck_text"/>

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/ratio_text"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="ratio"
            android:textSize="15pt"
            android:layout_below="@+id/fy_text"/>

    </RelativeLayout>

    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/input_Layout"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/input_text_Layout">

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/life_load"
            android:labelFor="@+id/life_load"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:inputType="number"
            android:ems="10" />

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/dead_load"
            android:labelFor="@+id/dead_load"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:inputType="number"
            android:ems="10"
            android:layout_below="@+id/life_load"/>

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/l"
            android:labelFor="@+id/l"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:inputType="number"
            android:ems="10"
            android:layout_below="@+id/dead_load"/>

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/fck"
            android:labelFor="@+id/fck"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:inputType="number"
            android:ems="10"
            android:layout_below="@+id/l"/>

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/fy"
            android:labelFor="@+id/fy"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:inputType="number"
            android:ems="10"
            android:layout_below="@+id/fck"/>

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/ratio"
            android:labelFor="@+id/ratio"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:inputType="number"
            android:ems="10"
            android:layout_below="@+id/fy"/>

    </RelativeLayout>

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/input_Layout"
        android:id="@+id/screen_value">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/rec_WH"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textSize="15pt"
            android:text="width_height" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/wheelStr"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textSize="15pt"
            android:text="wheelStrongth"
            android:layout_below="@+id/rec_WH"/>

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/ironStr"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textSize="15pt"
            android:text="ironStrength"
            android:layout_below="@id/wheelStr"/>

    </RelativeLayout>

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/input_Layout"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/screen_value">

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/btnCal"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="calculation" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/btnNext"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="next"
            android:layout_below="@+id/btnCal"/>

    </RelativeLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: I'm not sure It's the solution for you but do the findViewById calls in onCreate to be sure rather than class level. Because it can cause NullpointerExceptions. The reason is that you're trying to access an Id which haven't been created yet.

Comment: thx for your help, i'll doing in my home after work :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

All should be instantiated in onCreate()..

```
TextView recText ,wheelStr,ironStr ;
EditText editFck ,editFy ,edit_life_load,edit_dead_load,editL,editRatio;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

         recText = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.rec_WH);
    wheelStr = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.wheelStr);
    ironStr = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.ironStr);

    editFck = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.fck);
    editFy = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.fy);
    edit_life_load = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.life_load);
    edit_dead_load = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.dead_load);
    editL = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.l);
    editRatio = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.ratio);
    .....................
    ...................
```

Comment: More like "after `setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)`" than "in `onCreate()`" but still, thats probably the issue.

Comment: It means, your First problem solved, Is there any second problem, so please share lets solve it..

Comment: I think you need to be more careful reading what other people say and who they are. I'm not the one asking this question. I just pointed out a small logical error in your answer to this question.

Comment: don't worry about that, just sayin. Cheers.

Answer (score 1):

You can't initialize elements or controls outside of `onCreate()` function

You'll have to initialize inside of it.

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    Button btnCal;
    TextView recText, wheelStr, ironStr;
    EditText editFck, editFy, edit_life_load, edit_dead_load, editL, editRatio;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        /* OTHER CODE */
        recText = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.rec_WH);
        wheelStr = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.wheelStr);
        ironStr = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.ironStr);
        editFck = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.fck);
        editFy = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.fy);
        edit_life_load = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.life_load);
        edit_dead_load = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.dead_load);
        editL = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.l);
        editRatio = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.ratio);
        /* OTHER CODE */
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you need to assing id from resources in onCreate() method:

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
     super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
     setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
     editFck = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.fck);
     ......
 }
```

Comment: This is wrong, the findViewById should only happen after setContentView

Answer (score 0):

Instead of doing like

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
Button btnCal;

TextView recText = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.rec_WH);
TextView wheelStr = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.wheelStr);
TextView ironStr = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.ironStr);

EditText editFck = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.fck);
EditText editFy = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.fy);
EditText edit_life_load = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.life_load);
EditText edit_dead_load = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.dead_load);
EditText editL = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.l);
EditText editRatio = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.ratio);
```

you've to put all these in **onCreate**

```
TextView recText ,wheelStr,ironStr ;
EditText editFck ,editFy ,edit_life_load,edit_dead_load,editL,editRatio;
 @Override
 protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
  super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
  setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

  recText = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.rec_WH);
  wheelStr = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.wheelStr);
  ironStr = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.ironStr);

  editFck = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.fck);
  editFy = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.fy);
  edit_life_load = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.life_load);
```